Delete nodes in singly linked list (two implementations)
I have two implementation for removal function. Method 1 does not work because the compiler said curr is borrowed.
What is the difference between while let Some(boxed_node) = curr and match curr?
Method 1
fn delete_method_1(&mut self, val: i32) {
    let mut curr = &mut self.head;

    while let Some(boxed_node) = curr {
        if boxed_node.val == val {
            *curr = boxed_node.next.take(); // it does not work
        } else {
            curr = &mut boxed_node.next
        }
    }
}

Error message of Method 1
while let Some(boxed_node) = curr {
   |                        ---------- `*curr` is borrowed here
26 |             if boxed_node.val == val {
27 |                 *curr = boxed_node.next.take(); // it does not work
   |                 ^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 `*curr` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed
   |                 borrow later used here

Method 2
fn delete_method_2(&mut self, val: i32) {
    let mut curr = &mut self.head;
    loop {
        match curr {
            None => return,
            Some(boxed_node) if boxed_node.val == val => {
                *curr = boxed_node.next.take();
            },
            Some(boxed_node) => {
                curr = &mut boxed_node.next;
            }
        }
    }
}

I expected Method 1 to work.

Would be nice to see the rest of the error message

I think this is highly relevant: Why does conditional assignment of a matched mutable reference cause borrow errors? It may not be a duplicate, but it should offer some insight in the compiler behavior in a similar scenario.

Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example, i.e. a piece of code we can copy into our editors (or the playground) and it will compile.

This is actually not really a difference between while let and match. If you wrote the second method to be exactly like the first it would look like this:
fn delete_method_2(&mut self, val: i32) {
    let mut curr = &mut self.head;

    loop {
        match curr {
            None => return,
            Some(boxed_node) => {
                if boxed_node.val == val {
                    *curr = boxed_node.next.take();
                } else {
                    curr = &mut boxed_node.next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And you'd get the exact same error.
What's actually happening is a little bit subtle. First of all, match ergonomics will dereference match scrutinees for you automatically. What's actuall happening
is this:
fn delete_method_2(&mut self, val: i32) {
    let mut curr = &mut self.head;

    loop {
        //    v Rust inserts this dereference...
        match *curr {
            None => return,
            //   vvvvvvv and this borrow automatically
            Some(ref mut boxed_node) => {
                if boxed_node.val == val {
                    *curr = boxed_node.next.take();
                } else {
                    curr = &mut boxed_node.next;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

The while let version looks pretty much the same. The problem here is that the line curr = &mut boxed_node.next forces boxed_node to be borrowed for the lifetime of curr. With fake lifetime annotations:
fn delete_method_2(&mut self, val: i32) {
    let mut curr = &'curr mut self.head;

    loop {
        match *curr {
            None => return,
            Some(ref 'curr mut boxed_node) => {
                if boxed_node.val == val {
                    *curr = boxed_node.next.take();
                } else {
                    //            we force the compiler to match this lifetime
                    //      vvvvv exactly
                    curr = &'curr mut boxed_node.next;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

So because boxed_node has to be borrowed for 'curr, we're not allowed to assign to *curr within that same scope. The borrow checker can't (yet) figure out that the two branches need to borrow boxed_node for different lifetimes.
When you separate the cases into two distinct match arms, however, the compiler can figure out the appropriate lifetimes to borrow boxed_node for in each case:
fn delete_method_2(&mut self, val: i32) {
    let mut curr = &'curr mut self.head;

    loop {
        match *curr {
            None => return,
            Some(ref '_ mut boxed_node) if boxed_node.val == val => {
                *curr = boxed_node.next.take();
            }
            Some(ref 'curr mut boxed_node) => {
                curr = &'curr mut boxed_node.next;
            }
        }
    }
}

In the first case, the compiler just needs to borrow boxed_node for the duration of the take call, after which curr isn't considered borrowed anymore and we can re-assign it.
In the second case, the compiler can borrow boxed_node for the 'curr lifetime.
There are probably a myriad technical mistakes in that explanation, but big picture I think that's what's going on.
